# Bootstrap navbar keep search icon in desktop view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, search, toggle, navbar

i've ran into a problem with the bootstrap navbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/353/

I want to use a search icon navbar-toggle on full width but collapse only works on mobile. The animation on desktop goes wrong. I've tried to put display css on the .in class but the animation still isn't right.

```
.collapse.in{
    display:none!Important; 
}
```

Is there a simple bootstrap solution for this?

Comment: Could you please re-describe your problem?

Comment: I've got 2 collapsing elements in my navbar on mobile; searchform and the menu. When i click the search button on mobile view the search form toggles. I would like to keep this on desktop view for the search. But not for the menu. So i would like to set breaking points for each collapsing element.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but could you try something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/354/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a simple solution!

Go to **http://getbootstrap.com/customize/** .
Than go to the section **"Grid system"**.
There you find the "input" **@grid-float-breakpoint**.
For example, in this field you can put "3000px".

Don't forget to include jQuery and bootstrap.js at the end of the body tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But i don't think this is the solution. I need the default collapse for the menu but for the search i need a different one.

By changing the breakpoint they would both change. So the navigation has to function normally but i would like to keep the search field appear and hide with a toggle on mobile and on desktop.